# VirtualBox cannot find validated exisiting .iso file

Tags: virtualbox, tails

I'm trying to run TAILS on VirtualBox and it doesn't find a valid iso file although it exists.

Comment: Please describe what exactly you downloaded and how you tried to use it with VirtualBox in as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ISO for Virtual machines. That should work fine.

**(1) You almost for sure got Tails for USB Keys.**

[Download Tails](https://tails.net/install/download/index.en.html)

> Download and verify (for USB sticks)

**(2) Down at the bottom:**

*To use Tails in a virtual machine or burn a Tails DVD, download our ISO image instead.*

Use the second link instead to get the ISO to make a virtual machine. This should work fine.  I installed Tails in VMware.

[Download VM ISO](https://tails.net/install/download-iso/index.en.html)